# gem update --system ERROR: While executing gem ... (URI::BadURIError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
zhijiejiaoyu01@MacBook-Air-2 ~ % gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (URI::BadURIError)
    both URI are relative
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:1109:in `merge'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/source.rb:236:in `enforce_trailing_slash'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/source.rb:181:in `load_specs'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:253:in `tuples_for'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:220:in `block in available_specs'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:94:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:94:in `each_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:215:in `available_specs'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:91:in `search_for_dependency'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:143:in `fetch_remote_gems'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:168:in `highest_remote_name_tuple'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:231:in `rubygems_target_version'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:276:in `update_rubygems'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:99:in `execute'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command.rb:328:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:253:in `invoke_command'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:193:in `process_args'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:151:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:56:in `run'
    /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

This error occurs when I update my gem. How do I fix it?

Comment: Tangential: I’d recommend leaving your system Ruby and gems alone.

Comment: This error occurs when I install cocoapods using sudo gem install cocoapods, who can help me！！！

Comment: I encountered the same problem. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

execute `gem sources -l`, and if there is extra blank lines in the result, try to execute `gem sources --remove ""`, remove the extra blank lines, and retry.